# Can Necromastery be purged?

Tags: dota-2

Since SF's third skill is considered a buff, would purge work to dispel it? If yes, will it reset the souls or just disable it for some time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it cannot be purged. For further detail you can take a look [on the wiki](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Shadow_Fiend#Necromastery).

Comment: Really? This answer got accepted? Why?

Comment: @Loko What is the problem with the answer ?

Comment: That wiki link? What should I get from that about purging necromastery?

Comment: @Loko Well it link to the ability necromastery which is exactly what the question is about and if you look the detail above the ability it state "cannot be purged" which answer the queston so yeah once again, what's the problem ?

Comment: Aha oh the icons above it yeah. Forgot about those. I thought something with the description. Thanks for the downvote though

Comment: I'd just like to clarify myself, I would have accepted both answers should that be possible, but nah, so I turned to chronology.

Comment: @whitehatwannabe No sorry my mistake. I forgot about the wiki actually having an icon that says if you can purge it or not. I thought he just gave you a link to the wiki and that's it. Like figure it out yourself.

Answer (score 6):

Purging buffs/debuffs is considered a **Normal Dispel**

You cannot **Dispel** necromastery. See here: http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Dispel#Normal_Dispel

I'm not gonna list them all.

**List of abilities that cannot be removed by normal dispels:**

> Sand King - Burrowstrike - Stun
>
> Sand King - Caustic Finale
>
> Shadow Demon - Soul Catcher
>
> Shadow Demon - Demonic Purge
>
> Shadow Fiend - Necromastery
>
> Shadow Fiend - Requiem of Souls - Aura
>
> Shadow Shaman - Shackles

Comment: Pop! goes the bubble; for a moment i really thought Shadow Demon could be viable against SF.. -_- . thnx man

Comment: SD is actually good against SF  lategame, where his illusions hurt as hell.

Comment: @Gowtham A lot of heroes are good against shadow fiend lategame. Shadow fiend is not good late game

Comment: SF maybe not as strong as AM,PL,Spectre etc. I agree. I am just saying SD is viable against SF(6 slotted) because of purge through BKB,free aura for SD team ,  as opposed to the above comment about unviable. Thats all.

Comment: @Gowtham Haha I know. I'm not disagreeing with you. Just wanted to add in that I think Shadow Fiend is way too overrated.